# yii cgridview afterAjaxUpdate not firing on pager

Tags: php, yii

[SOLVED]I have a page with a Cgridview.

AfterAjaxUpdate is firing once when the page is loaded but not further.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'Ticket-grid',
        'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
        'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:console.log("test")',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'template' => "{items}{summary}{pager}",
        'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered table-condensed',
        'filter' => $model,
        'columns' => array( // etc
```

AfterAjaxUpdate doesn't work on filtering or pagination updates.

Also no console errors.

SOLUTION ::

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'Ticket-grid',
    'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id,data){YourFunctionName()}',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'template' => "{items}{summary}{pager}",
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered table-condensed',
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array( // etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding update selector.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'Ticket-grid',
        'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
        'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:console.log("test")',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'template' => "{items}{summary}{pager}",
        'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered table-condensed',
        'filter' => $model,
        'updateSelector'=>'custom-page-selector', //update selector
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        'columns' => array( // etc
```

Comment: Works good. Would like the page not to load though as it adds the requested page in the url. We usually refresh the page to go back to the first page as their are about 60 pages. I will add custom css to put first page static button on pager.

Comment: Checkout the answer on top. @ProgrammingStudent